# Storing & retrieving signed values from a bit field

Tags: c++, sqlite, bit-manipulation

I need to store and retrieve a signed integer value to / from a signed 64 bit integer column (BigInt) in SQLite. For simplicity suppose the field is taking up the first BitCount bits of the the BigInt. Also assume we want to change the bit field in the record with RowID = :RowID to :Val and note that the bits used by the field are FldBits = (1 << BitCount) - 1.

If it were an unsigned value the storing and retrieval are straightforward enough.

```
// Store
update BigIntTbl set BigInt = BigInt & ~FldBits | :Val
where RowID=:RowID; 

// Retrieve
select BigInt & FldBits
from BigIntTbl where RowID=:RowID;
```

I'm assuming (but I'm by no means sure) that the best way to store a signed value is to set :Val to the twos complement bits for a negative value before storing. I've came up with the following formula but can't help but feel I'm making things hard for myself.

```
// Store
update BigIntTbl set BigInt = BigInt & ~FldBits |
(:Val + (:Val<0) * (1 << BitCount))
// above sets :Val to 2s complement bit pattern for -ve values and leaves +ve values unchanged

// Retreive
select (BigInt & FldBits) - 2 * (BigInt & (1 << (BitCount-1)))
from BigIntTbl where RowID=:RowID;
```

I did think about just applying an offset (i.e. add offset when storing, deduct offset when retrieving) but, for reasons I won't go into, I want zero to be stored as zero. For the sake of clarity assume the sign bit (bit 63) in BigInt is never used.

Questions:

1. Can I replace
   `(:Val + (:Val<0) * (1 << BitCount))`
   with
   `(:Val & FldBits)`
2. Anything simpler than
   `(BigInt & FldBits) - 2 * (BigInt & (1 << (BitCount-1)))`
   for retrieval?

Comment: Redo the table to put separate data in separate fields.  That's what databases are for.

Comment: Why do you want to do Bit operations inside a database, i would use the database just for storing the raw data, if you want to do Bit operations on  them, get them out of the database, and then do the operation.

Comment: LOL stark. I didn't get where I am today by putting separate data in separate fields. Seriously though, a packed key can speed up reads.

Comment: Alex, why would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION (I hope)

Take the general case of a 64 bit signed integer BigInt and consider a signed bit field that starts at bit LoBit (0 based) and occupies BitCount bits.

```
FldBits = ((1 << BitCount) - 1) << LoBit;
```

You can store any number Val between -(1 << (BitCount - 1)) and (1 << (BitCount - 1)) - 1 with

```
BigInt = BigInt & ~FldBits | (Val << LoBit & FldBits)
```

and retrieve it with

```
Val = (BigInt & FldBits) << (64 - BitCount - LoBit) >> (64 - BitCount);
```

A simple SQL example

```
select (?1 & 31) << 59 >> 59;
```

Any value between -16 and 15 for ?1 will return ?1 (compare with 'select ?1 & 31').

The two way shift results in the top bit of bit field being replicated in all higher bits. If Val is a +ve number that means it's padded with zeroes. If Val is -ve it's padded with ones which results in the 64 bit integer containing the 64 bit representation of Val.